# What are the brackets before a function in Rust?

Tags: rust

What is the purpose of the brackets in function declarations. For instance what's the difference between the following:

```
/// without brackets
pub fn new_with_now(now: T) -> SomeType

/// with brackets
pub fn new_with_now<T: Now>(now: T) -> SomeType
```

Comment: First one expects concrete type which is a `T` unless function is not defined in some generic implementation. Second one expects any type which implements `Now`, it is also called generic function.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer is in the doc: [Generics](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/generics.html)

> A type parameter is specified as generic by the use of angle brackets
>   and upper camel case: . "Generic type parameters" are
>   typically represented as . In Rust, "generic" also describes
>   anything that accepts one or more generic type parameters . Any
>   type specified as a generic type parameter is generic, and everything
>   else is concrete (non-generic).

Your second definition is a type restriction to `T` requiring an implementation of `Now` (whatever that may be). In turn, below the hood, the compiler will generate a variant of `new_with_now` for every `struct` used that implements `Now` and calls this function at any given point.